# Shared as usual to service account, calendar does not appear in the list when querying it from Calendar API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I have around 51 Google calendars shared to a google service account and they are still working well, I am getting push notification from them on a regular basis. I added one more calendar in the usual way with: "share to other people" and set e-mail to my service account. I then tried to get a list of all calendars that are connected to the service account I can not get the newest one. It is absent.

Here is the Joomla php code I have used for the past 2-3 years:

```
public function loadCalendarList() {

    $this->user = JFactory::getUser();
    if ($this->_connect()) {
        **$list = $this->_service->calendarList->listCalendarList();**
        if (!empty($list['items'])) {
....
```

All calendars except new one are loaded.
I have search all over internet but no clue,
I am not using G Suite.
If I use google OAuth 2.0 authorisation without any service account I can load all 52 calendar with the new one.
One more thought: I have not added to this new calendar for several months, I think something changed in google?

Comment: Spelling, grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newly shared calendars, after sharing a calendar with the service account, you need to explicitly insert it into the service account's calendar list. Something like this:

```php
$newCalendar=new Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
$newCalendar->setId("THE ID OF THE NEWLY ADDED CALENDAR");
$service->calendarList->insert($newCalendar);
```

Comment: Thanks, your masterful answer give a hope, i wil try. One question to understand : - is it just standalone procedure, a have to run my own program ( with your code) just to make service account and this new calendar frends forever?  Thanks and happy new year

Comment: Yes, what I provided are some additional lines to incorporate into your existent code where you define and use the service account (e.g. your `public function loadCalendarList()` where you list all calendars of the service account - just incorporate the additional lines to insert the new calendar, before you list all calendars. I assume that `$service` is defined somewhere in your code).

Comment: Thanks a lot, am happy

Comment: I am happy to accept it, but i cant find on the page the word accept, except 1 in your comment, I clicked Up arrow in the top of your answer, thanks

Comment: Here is some explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers